# convert method to generic with multiple data types

Tags: java, generics

I Try to convert my method in java into a generic method, but it does not work. My problem is, that i have two data types as Parameter.

My method is:

```
public static int whichInt(int[] a, char[] b) { ...
```

My solution was something like this:

```
public static <T,S extends Comparable<T,S>> int whichint(T[]a, S[] b){ ...
```

Does somebody know how to write this method correctly?
Best regards,

Comment: There is no `Comparable<X,Y>` interface. A type can only be comparable with *one* other type (or the same type). What is it that you are trying to say about your two types? What is the relationship between them?

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the parameters from Array to List or Set or Collection..

```
public static <T,S> int whichInt(Collection<T> a,Collection<S> b)
```

Java does not support Generics in Array..
Reference : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. If I would have data types which are not array(s), would the syntax then be correct:public static <T,S extends Comparable<T,S>> int whichint(T a, S b){ ...

Comment: @marciano Yes, if you can change your parameter type from Array to Collection then above syntax is correct .. But if you want to make any relation ship between **S** and **T**  , then you have to define that relationship using **super** or **extend**  ..Like you did a bit in Question

Comment: Thanks for your answer !